# Spliting a String in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Is there a way to split the following `string` (containing variables `x1, x2, x3`)

`3x1+5x2-8x3<=9`

into the following tokens

`{3, 1, +5, 2, -8, 3, 9}`

Comment: Some of the operators are being considered tokens and others are being eliminated. I think you need to specify the rules for what determines a token.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: `string.Split` can easily do the job if the rules be more consistent

Comment: This is a simplex method restriction. The number before the x is the coeficient, for example ```3x1``` means ```3*x1```. I need to get the coeficient and the variable number(x1, x2, ...). My biggest problem is with that minus signal...

Comment: @slugster I could split and get both numbers, but I wasn't able to get that signal..

Comment: @Ian I've tried, but I can't get that regex out of my head. I'm kinda newbie with regexes

Comment: There is no such direct method but we can do some trick on it ,Like You nee only + ,- symbol to be with no ,right?

Comment: I get it... they are actually variables... x1, x2, x3

Comment: if you replace "-" with "+-" and similar with "<=" it's as simple as `"3x1+5x2-8x3<=9".Replace("-","+-").Replace("<=","<").Split([|'x';'+';'<'|])` (note: F# syntax right from FSI - but should be obvious in C#): `[|"3"; "1"; "5"; "2"; "-8"; "3"; "9"|]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the case is not as complex, I would probably solve such issue by using `string.Split` instead of `Regex`:

```
string str = "3x1+5x2-8x3<=9";
str = str.Replace("+", "x+").Replace("-", "x-");
string[] words = str.Split(new string[] {"x", "<=", ">=", "<", ">"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The idea is to make `"x"` the separator apart from the inequalities. I also put `"<="` and `">="` inequalities before `"<"` and `">"`. This is done to avoid `"<"` found before `"<="`

Comment: I didn't think about replacing the minus signal with something else, thank you Sir, it did the trick ;)

Comment: @FrankTominc ah yes, glad that it helps. Initially I mistakenly took your `x` as multiplication sign instead of variable x1, x2, x3... After a second look, I just realize it.. ;) I edited your question to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression for that and extract only numbers with signs:

```
const string str = "3x1+5x2-8x3<=9";
var result = Regex.Matches(str, @"([\+\-]?[\d]+)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Result:

```
[0] "3" string
[1] "1" string
[2] "+5"    string
[3] "2" string
[4] "-8"    string
[5] "3" string
[6] "9" string
```